# c# searching data from json file

Tags: c#

I have one json file in my site. I want that my c# script read the json file and search if my ip is in the file.
This is my json file:

```
[    
    { 
        "licenzaAttiva":true, 
        "webhook":"",
         "nomeServer": "Name of the server", 
         "idDiscordCliente": "Id Discord", 
         "nomeDiscordCliente": "My Name", 
         "ip": "my ip", 
         "licenza": "license"
    },
    { 
        "licenzaAttiva":true, 
        "webhook":"",
         "nomeServer": "Name of the server", 
         "idDiscordCliente": "Id Discord", 
         "nomeDiscordCliente": "My Name", 
         "ip": "my ip", 
         "licenza": "license"
    },
    { 
        "licenzaAttiva":true, 
        "webhook":"",
         "nomeServer": "Name of the server", 
         "idDiscordCliente": "Id Discord", 
         "nomeDiscordCliente": "My Name", 
         "ip": "my ip", 
         "licenza": "license"
    }
]
```

This is my class in c#

```
public class Dati
{
    public string webhook { get; set; }
    public string nomeServer { get; set; }
    public string idDiscordCliente { get; set; }
    public string nomeDiscordCliente { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string licenza { get; set; }
    public bool licenzaAttiva { get; set; }

}
```

This is my code

```
public static void Read()
{
   string site = "";
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string data = wc.DownloadString(site);

                var datiJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dati>>(data);
                string myip = "myip";
}
```

now I want that my scrip read the json file into my site and search if the variable myip is into the file. Can someone help me?

Comment: you can use linq, somthing like: datiJson.Where(x=>x.ip.Equals(myip));

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var result = datiJson.Any(p=> p.ip.Equals(myip));
```